# Must declare scalar variable in sql....with input and output parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got SP that gets USER_ID as input and fetches GROUP_ID from the table, but it shows error when I'm trying to run it:

> must declare scalar variable @Group_i

My stored procedure:

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[DisplayDetails] 

@User_Id int,
@Group_Id int OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

Begin
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT 
@Group_Id=(select distinct(Group_Id) from input_files_updated)   
 from INPUT_FILES_updated where [User_Id]=@User_Id

END
END

GO
```

Query to execute SP:

```
Declare @Group_I int    

Execute [dbo].[DisplayDetails] @User_Id='3',    
@Group_Id=@Group_I out
```

Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Tag the dbms product! (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: WHY IS THE CAPS-LOCK ON?

Comment: @Group_I is showing must declare scalar variable

Comment: `Execute [dbo].[Proc_Ideator_DisplayDetails] @User_Id='3',   
@Group_Id=@Group_I outPUT` and if distinct will return more then 1 value?

Comment: same error still :(

Comment: `Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[DisplayDetails] ` and then `Execute [dbo].[Proc_Ideator_DisplayDetails]` is that right?

Comment: no I am checking for user id without duplication...even for that it doesn't work. so distinct doesn't come in preference

Comment: ya.. I checked this too..stored procedure name ..still same

Answer (score 2):

A little bit fixed query of yours:

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[DisplayDetails] 
    @User_Id int,
    @Group_Id int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT @Group_Id = (
    select top 1 Group_Id
    from INPUT_FILES_updated 
    where [User_Id]=@User_Id
)

RETURN  
END
```

As I remember there must be a word RETURN in SP. Then try:

```
Declare @Group_I int    

Execute [dbo].[DisplayDetails] @User_Id=3, @Group_Id=@Group_I output

SELECT @Group_I
```

Comment: Look, I just have created table `INPUT_FILES_updated` with two columns `User_id` and `Group_Id` Then I add there two values `(3,5)`, then I create SP like below in my answer, then I run part with DECLARE and EXECUTE and ALL is **working fine**

Comment: i created a new table to verify if there is some problem with table.. but for me for same proc the error still persists..what should i do"?

Comment: I hope you execute full part from `DECLARE to OUTPUT` and not only `EXEC..OUTPUT`

Comment: now, if i execute from declare to output.. it give command executed successfully but no output is fetched .. i want group_id 5 to be shown right?

Comment: Oh my! add `SELECT @Group_I` (add this to answer)

Comment: oops..i love you for this :)

Comment: Finally it works! Don't forger to execute ALL batch, if you select only a part of your query and press F5 only chosen part will be executed! If the answers helps you, be free to upvote/accept it, that's a nice way to say "thanks"!